# Authorization Code Grant: Can i use access token as an Authorization Token for my API?

Tags: http, security, oauth-2.0, oauth

im trying to implement the "Sign in with X"-Login for my Webapi. My Client is a native app. Can/Should i exchange the authorization code for an access token client-side? Can i use given access token as an access-token for my backend?

Or should i send the Authorization Code to my backend where it is exchanged for an access token with the identity provider? Could i use this token as an Auth-Token for my backend or should i generate a new token just for my backend?

I am not sure, what the implications of each of these approaches would be. The first approach would lead to the deployment of my client secret. My identity provider does not allow the creation of public clients.

Thanks!

Comment: If everything goes through your backend, it's *more* secure if the access token never leaves the backend. You *could* use the access token for your own purposes if you have a means to validate it, but not doing this is a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

I see that there are two questions in your post:

1. Should I exchange the authorization code for tokens in my frontend client or in my backend?
2. Can I use the external access token to access my APIs?

Here are the answers:

1. If you have an option to handle the exchange in the backend, you should do it there. This way you keep the tokens out of your app, thus reducing the surface of a potential attack. For your front-end client, you should still establish some kind of user session. You can achieve this by issuing either plain-old HTTP session cookies or your own access tokens.
2. You should never use an external access token to authorize access to your APIs. That access token is meant to be used to access the provider's APIs. You have no control over the content of that token, so for example, you can't limit the token's scope (using your scope or claim values). You might have limited options to validate that token, or that validation will rely on the external service (e.g. you will have to call that external service on every request to your API to validate the token). When using the "log in with X" functionality what you should do is to get the ID token from the provider. That token gives you information about the authenticated user. You should take that information and create your own user session (again either through cookies or your own access tokens). That way you will have full control over the authorization of your API requests.